# How to buffer overflow the 'gets' method in Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I wrote a client that gets input from the keyboard and stores it in a variable, like so:

```
x = gets
```

In C, normally memory is allocated for standard input and thus I can easily overflow the buffer and overwrite the return address on the stack if I write enough characters to the buffer.

```
char buffer[10];
gets(buffer);
```

How can I go about overflowing the buffer used in Ruby? I haven't had luck on finding information pertaining to how to exploit programs that are NOT written in C. I've been following a book called "The Shellcoder's Handbook" and everything is in C. Are there any resources I could look at that explain how to exploit programs written in other languages, especially in Ruby? Or is there definitely a reason why most exploit books are written for the C language, as other languages would be too advanced?

Based on observation, it seems as if I can feed as many characters as I want to to the 'gets' method in Ruby and it will not overflow, making it protected from overflow exploits.

Comment: Ruby is written in C. ;)

In general, you need to be able to write directly to memory to exploit buffer overflows and Ruby does not allow that. However, bugs will be bugs and it does happen every now and then.

http://xforce.iss.net/xforce/xfdb/89191

Comment: Most C exploits take advantage of C's permissiveness and general lack of safety checks. Whereas all Ruby code essentially runs in a VM - abstracted away from the actual system memory. If you want to write a Ruby exploit, you're going to need to find a bug in the interpreter.

Comment: Why do you want to exploit other programs?